# How does one properly make a page layout using css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

bellow is my attempt at making a page layout using grid. However, the scroll bar is under the header.

[image]

rather than taking up the  entire height of the page.

[image]

This occurs because I added `overflow:auto` to the **section** tag. As I'm not familiar enough with using the grid layout, I'm not sure how to properly achieve a page layout using grid. Is there a way around this? Is there a better solution to achieve what I'm trying to do?

```css
body {
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 200px) auto;
            grid-template-rows:  54px auto;
            grid-template-areas: "header header"
                                "nav    section";
        }

        header {
            grid-area: header;
            background: red;
        }

        nav {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            grid-area: nav;
            background: blue;
        }
        section {
            grid-area: section;
            background: yellow;
            overflow:auto;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<body>
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div>
            navigation
            <br> I'm at the top
        </div>
        <div>
            I'm at the bottom
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. You mention why the scrollbar exists in the section, and not the whole page—the `overflow: auto` rule. If you remove it, the scroll will appear covering the whole page.

Comment: @AndyHoffman, It will but then the navigation and the header scrolls with the page, and to prevent that from happening one then needs to use  `position: fixed`.  on both the `nav` and the `header` as well as adjust the `width` and `height`. so if ones has to do this anyway then what was the point of setting up a page layout using grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, scrollbar is under the header because of

```
body{
   height:100vh;
 }
```

set

```
body{
 min-height:100vh;
}
```

now if you set body `min-height:100vh` this would make entire body scroll instead of section.This would stretch nav to the same height as section `because second row height in grid is auto`.

> Is there a way around this? Is there a better solution to achieve what I'm trying to do?

i think you should not use css grid for this type of layout because `section` height will vary in most of cases and this would also make nav height change.
In your example you have to scroll to the bottom of section to click or have access to the last element in navbar(or sidebar), which would be very bad UX when section height will be more than `100vh`.

i would suggest to make navbar `position:fixed` to the left side, and use css grid to position elements on remaining right side.

Comment: every time i read up on css-grids I see examples such as the image in the link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp Even the first explanation of a grids says, "The CSS Grid Layout Module offers a grid-based layout system, with rows and columns, making it easier to design web pages without having to use floats and positioning." So maybe this is why I assumed that a page layout like the one I was trying to make was possible. :(

Comment: "i would suggest to make navbar position:fixed to the left side, and use css grid to position elements on remaining right side." wouldn't using grid on the left affect the header's length, so a position of fixed will also need to be used. And so all that would remain is the section so why use grid at all? I think I'm confused about the use of css-grids in relation to page layouts.

Comment: simple answers is that you **can not** use css-grid for this type of layout. css grid is useful for content layout. first create layout than inside that you can use css-grid for laying out your content like images.

Comment: this codepen demo explain how to use position fixed and css-grid for this type of layout [link](https://codepen.io/joeaugie/pen/GvVgKL?editors=1100)

Comment: In the link you gave, wouldn't it be much easier to just give page a `margin-left:20vw; rather than having o set up a grid and adjusting both page and main. I'm honestly not seeing the advantages of using grid in these cases.

Comment: Yes, you are right, using ``margin-left:20vw`` or ``padding-left:20vw`` would do the same, there is no need to use css-grid for this type of simple purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To show a other possibility take a look at the following example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 200px) auto;
}

header {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  height: var(--header-height);
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  grid-column: 1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
}
section {
  background: yellow;
  overflow:auto;
  grid-column: 2;
  margin-top: var(--header-height);
}

:root {
  --header-height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<body>
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div>
            navigation
            <br> I'm at the top
        </div>
        <div>
            I'm at the bottom
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
        section
        <br>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have now made the navigation able to grow and scroll together with the section